# Granger representation theorem - reverse always true?

Tags: cointegration, vector-error-correction-model

The Granger representation theorem claims that a vector error correction model can be transformed into a "common trend representation" (processes share the same stochastic trend) if some criteria are met.

Is the opposite always true? 
Can we always transform a model in the common term representation form to the vector error correction model form?